# Populate dropdown list with database values and split up alphabetical sorting

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

I am populating a list of organisations into a dropdown list on my website. This PHP is easy and I have had no problems with it.

However, the list will potentially become quite vast and I'd like to split the list into three alphabetical sections. (A-G, H-S, T-Z for example). How can I modify my code below to accommodate sorting the first dropdown list with A-G (I can then apply the same logic to the other two).

```
   $sql = pg_query("SELECT name FROM institution ORDER BY name ASC");                                                                 
   while($row = pg_fetch_array($sql)){
      echo "<option value=\"organisation1\">" .$row ['name'] . "</option>";
   }
```

Comment: fetch your date before you do a while, and do some processing such as substring to find the first letter of 'name' and then conditional (if) in A to G logic. else H-S else T-Z. OR in a really funky way do the logic in your SQL with a where clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$sql = pg_query("
    select name
    from institution
    where name < 'H'
    order by name asc
");

$sql = pg_query("
    select name
    from institution
    where name >= 'H' and  name < 'T'
    order by name asc
");

$sql = pg_query("
    select name
    from institution
    where name >= 'T'
    order by name asc
");
```

Comment: works perfectly thank you. Didn't realise SQL provided a <> operator functions.

Answer (score 1):

If the end users are likely to know the names of the organisations then you may be better off with a search box and some JS to populate based on the letters typed.

Otherwise you might want to have an additional initial drop down list to split the list by a logical breakdown instead of alphabetically (eg country, city, department)

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick of A-G and H-S

```
    $AG = $HS = '';
$sql = pg_query("SELECT name FROM institution ORDER BY name ASC");                                                                 
while($row = pg_fetch_array($sql)){
    $char =chr(strtoupper(substr($row ['name'],0,1)));
    if($char<=71){
        $AG .= "<option value=\"organisation1\">" .$row ['name'] . "</option>";
    }
   if(($char>71) && ($char <= 83)){
         $HS .= "<option value=\"organisation1\">" .$row ['name'] . "</option>";
    }
   }
   echo $AG.$HS;
```

Use chr to get the ascii value of the 1st character. Create conditionals to add strings to your subsections. You can look the ASCII vals up here:
http://www.asciitable.com/

Comment: I can see the logic behind your code and to me if should work but it doesn't appear to be working? I have just included the AG conditional for the first select box/dropdown list and left out anything to do with $HS. Any ideas why it isn't working? I can provide my code on the page if required.

Comment: How does $AG look? It should contain only the data-part of the select, you still need to wrap a `<select>` around it to see any HTML output. Also, the actual value of each option is the same for all which you may or may not want.

Answer (score 0):

```
$cityarray = array('axx', 'bxx','txx');

$group1 = array('a','b','c','d','e','f');
$group2  = 'construct array with the require alphapet';
$group3  = 'construct array with the require alphapet';


foreach (cityarray as $city) {
 if (in_array($city[0], group1)) {
   $group1[] = $city 
 } else if (in_array($city[0], group2) {
   $group2[] = $city 
 }  else if (in_array($city[0], group3) {
   $group3[] = $city 
}
```

}

//Use the above three arrays to construct the dropdown

Answer (score 0):

am not a php  or postgresql guy, but what you need is a simple programming logic. and simple algo should suffice it.

```
step1. run a loop through the array to fill dropdowns.

step2. place appropriate conditions inside the loop to fill all the three dropdowns appropriately.
```

see this code. supporting the algo. you might need to trim it a little bit for your language

```
 $sql = pg_query("SELECT name FROM institution ORDER BY name ASC");

   $ddlClass='.dropdown1';                                                                 

   while($row = pg_fetch_array($sql)){
         $char = chr(strtoupper(substr($row ['name'],0,1)));

         if($char>=65 && $char<=71);
            $ddlClass=  '.dropdown1';

         else if($char>=72 && $char<=83);
           $ddlClass=  '.dropdown2';

         else if ($char>=83 && $char <=90)
            $ddlClass=  '.dropdown3';
         $($ddlClass).append("<option value=\"organisation1\">" .$row ['name'] . "</option>");
 }
```

I've used jquery to create your dropdown, you can use anything else i.e. javascript, php to do so.